# How do you handle long, thin Shape Land uses in Dawn of Worlds

Tags: homebrew, dawn-of-worlds

A frequent issue in Dawn of Worlds with our group occurs when players want to make rivers, cliff edges, etc.  The Shape Land power allows editing in a 1" diameter area, which makes the creation of linear landforms expensive compared to circular ones (or, really, landforms which can be built out of 1" circles).  A secondary problem is that, if left half-done, these landforms can end up not making any sense, with rivers shaped like dotted lines and M.C.Escher-esque cliff topology.  How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean "dotted lines"? If you keep extending a river, you should never get any dots. Likewise with a cliff face.

Comment: @Erik If, instead of extending a river, you make each 1" section of the river you're imagining in order of how much fun it is to draw/how important is to the world and then stop filling it in before doing the boring/unimportant bits because there's other things to do/the Age ends, you get dotted lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual [rules](http://www.clanwebsite.org/games/rpg/Dawn_of_Worlds_game_1_0Final.pdf) for Shape Land say:

> On the game map, this power allows the creation of land forms within a 1 inch diameter area. Roughly.

I do not believe it is reasonable, or intended by the designers, to interpret this as requiring all the changes to fall strictly within a 1" circle, especially not with the explicit "roughly" in the rules text.  Obviously, like most things in Dawn of Worlds, this is subject to personal interpretation, but I would say that if you wish to use a single Shape Land to create, say, a 10" river that's clearly narrower than 3/10", it should be fine.

(Of course, it's possible to abuse this to create absurd landforms that obstruct or interfere with other geographical features, but that's going to be possible anyway. Remember that this is a game that, strictly according to the rules, lets you turn an entire prosperous country into an impassable mountain range / barren glacier / lake of lava / radioactive wasteland with a single Shape Land/Climate action.  To keep the game from degenerating into pointless chaos, some cooperation and common sense is required.)

---

Personally, if an explicit limit was actually needed, I might house-rule that the Shape Land power could be used to affect any [convex region](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set) whose area is about 3 square inches<sup>*</sup> or less.  This should rule out most obvious abuses, while still allowing reasonably natural landforms — sure, you could make a straight wall across the entire map, but why would you?  The most obvious issue with this rule, though, is that it would make long curved landforms more expensive than straight ones, which might be undesirable.  (Then again, many large rivers and mountain ranges IRL *are* fairly straight on the large scale, so...)

<sup>*) If you use gridded paper, there's a [clever trick](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) for quickly estimating the area of a arbitrary region by approximating it with a polygon drawn on the grid.  Or you could just eyeball it.  Besides, the rules don't actually say [how large the map should be](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55887/how-large-should-the-large-sheet-of-paper-be), so the 1" radius should presumably be taken as an arbitrary figure that may be scaled up or down as desired.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I think there's two solutions, pick whichever you think works best for you:

1)

One way to deal with, as you say in the comment, "the boring/unimportant bits" is to simply draw them into the map when you realise that nobody cares enough either way to spend points on filling in the remainder. (This can be at the end of an Age or even at the end of the whole game)

It's a shared game, so if nobody has a strong opinion on what there should be in some of the pieces of the map that are still blank at some point is to simply draw what makes sense: the river continues through them in the dullest way possible.

If anyone wants to actually do something interesting on the other hand; let them. If somebody decides that he wants to spend his point to make the river flow underground through one of these patches, that's totally valid and should always overrule the boring "nobody willing to spend points" answer.

2)

The other way is to not allow features that make no sense on their own. You can't draw a river that goes from nowhere to nowhere. Either you spend the points to make the whole river, or you cannot draw the interesting parts yet.

This makes all the terrain features make more sense, but also gives other players less options to do crazy stuff to the terrain segments that the creator of that part thinks aren't important enough to draw.

The first will probably give you a crazier, more magical world, while the second will give a more consistent and believable world. Pick whichever you're aiming for.