# How large should the Large Sheet of Paper be?

Tags: map-making, tool-recommendation, dawn-of-worlds

I always get one that's too big.  We play with 3-5 people and don't want to spend more than two and a half hours straight drawing landscape at the absolute longest. What size paper would be best?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've played the game once and we used an A2 sheet of paper (okay, okay, we used 2 pieces of A3 taped together...) and another A3 sheet for recording the world's history. We didn't spend very long drawing landscape, but that was more because of keeping things broad then because of the size of the paper.

If you look at the document and the example in it about drawing "9 points of terrain" then it appears that what they are using an A3 size paper. (9 points = 3 inch, and the mountain range takes up 25% of the size of the paper, which means it's 12 inch on the short size, which means it's A3)

We realised while playing that this makes things pretty small and that it'd only work for a fairly compact kind of place. Since we were looking for a D&D campaign setting with a few dozen races and kingdoms, we used A2 and then doubled the sizes of all the modifications. This gave us much more space to write names and draw borders, as well as a higher number of special terrain features that we could add with name.

It also meant we didn´t draw forests made of small trees as in the example, but simply drew an area and wrote " forest" in it.

So depending on what you're going for:

1. If you're going for something small scale (ie; writing a book)
   then pick an A3 like in the example
2. If you're going large scale (ie; a campaign setting or an epic), then pick an A2 but make sure you double the size of all the spells and skip on the detail in favor of writing more names on the map

Also, if you're going to use Dawn of Worlds to create an RPG setting, it'll be awesome. It's a real shame we never had time to run through the entire world we'd made, but to give you an idea of the kind of things that happen through Dawn of Worlds:

At some point, one of the players decided that one of the races would have their homecity lifted into the sky by the gods, becoming a flying chunk of rock with a city. The race later got an Order that favored magical experimentation on living creatures. Somewhere near the end of the game, another player played a Catastrophy to disrupt the magic keeping the city afloat.

The campaign started within the crashed city. It lay inside the lake that was created when the chunk was lifted, under a steep incline, with the lower sections of the city totally submerged in the lake. Most of it was destroyed, the surrounding countryside was full of escaped magical experiments. It was an amazing place to start play, but it still took a lot of time for the players decide that it was the *best* starting point, because there were many contenders. You can't make this stuff up on your own :)

Comment: +1 for the deconstruction of the provided example.  I totally should have thought of that.